# Tag suggestion: [icon-fonts]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

I recently made a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857281/how-to-track-changes-to-icon-fonts) regarding icon-fonts and there were no [icon-fonts](/questions/tagged/icon-fonts) tag.

**icon-fonts** is the new way to embed small images in webpages.
Google returns about 29M pages with that keyword: https://www.google.com/search?q=icon-fonts

Should we add an [icon-fonts](/questions/tagged/icon-fonts) tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [icon-fonts](/questions/tagged/icon-fonts) tag has just been created.

Now off you go and suggest a great tag wiki & excerpt :-)